# Improving the Performance of this Stored Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, database-performance, insert-into

I am attempting to optimize this Stored Procedure. Currently, this iteration when done from the very top of the chain, can take about 2.4-2.7 seconds. I would love to get this down to below 1 second if possible.

I have done research on what I can do to optimize this and most of MySQL's own tips do not work. You cannot `LOCK` tables or use the `LOAD DATA` statements inside Stored Procedures. When running tests, it appears that the `INSERT INTO SELECT` statements are taking the most time inside this query.

When I ran one CALL, I got 2.6 seconds with around 13 `INSERT INTO` statements firing off. At least 3 took 0.43-0.45 seconds to complete. All other statements took very little time to complete.

Here is my current settings inside my 'my.cnf' file:

```
default-storage-engine = MyISAM
key_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup = ON
innodb_sort_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
read_buffer_size = 4M
thread_stack = 256K
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64MB
```

Here is my Stored Procedure:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE lastLayer INT;
    DECLARE lastInsertCount INT;
    DECLARE tempTableRowCount INT;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp`;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pendingBusiness`;


    CREATE TABLE `temp`
    (
        `layer` INT(5),
        `title_c` VARCHAR(255), 
        `name` VARCHAR(255), 
        `rep_first_name` VARCHAR(255), 
        `rep_last_name` VARCHAR(255),
        `id_c` CHAR(36),
        `contact_status_reps_c` VARCHAR(255),
        `phone_mobile` VARCHAR(255),
        `contract_type_c` VARCHAR(255),
        `email_address` VARCHAR(255)
    );


    CREATE TABLE `pendingBusiness`
    (
        `layer` INT(5),
        `title_c` VARCHAR(255), 
        `name` VARCHAR(255), 
        `rep_first_name` VARCHAR(255), 
        `rep_last_name` VARCHAR(255),
        `id_c` CHAR(36),
        `contact_status_reps_c` VARCHAR(255),
        `investor_first_name` VARCHAR(255),
        `investor_last_name` VARCHAR(255),
        `product_detail` VARCHAR(255),
        `paperwork_status_c` VARCHAR(255),
        `next_step` VARCHAR(255),
        `outstanding_requirements_c` VARCHAR(255),
        `funding_status_c` VARCHAR(255),
        `funding_next_step_c` VARCHAR(255),
        `fulfillment_status_c` VARCHAR(255),
        `fulfillment_next_step_c` VARCHAR(255),
        `amount` VARCHAR(255),
        `stage` VARCHAR(255),
        `date_entered` DATETIME,
        `case_manager` VARCHAR(255),
        `lost_sale_date_c` DATETIME,
        `compensation_run_c` DATETIME,
        `product_id` CHAR(36),
        `rep_state` VARCHAR(255),
        `investor_state` VARCHAR(255)
    );

    INSERT INTO `temp`(`layer`, `title_c`, `name`, `rep_first_name`, `rep_last_name`, `id_c`, `contact_status_reps_c`, `phone_mobile`,`contract_type_c`,`email_address`)
    SELECT 0,
    wn_writing_number_cstm.title_c, 
    wn_writing_number.`name`, 
    preps_contracted_reps.first_name, 
    preps_contracted_reps.last_name, 
    wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c, 
    preps_contracted_reps_cstm.contact_status_reps_c, 
    preps_contracted_reps.phone_mobile, 
    preps_contracted_reps_cstm.contract_type_c, 
    email_addresses.email_address
FROM wn_writing_number LEFT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing946b_number_ida = wn_writing_number.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp ON wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing3148nt_comp_idb = cac_customize_agent_comp.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm ON cac_customize_agent_comp.id = cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c
     LEFT OUTER JOIN aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c = aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.aos_produca2b8nt_comp_idb
     LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1wn_writing_number_idb = wn_writing_number.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_cont9effed_reps_ida = preps_contracted_reps.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps_cstm ON preps_contracted_reps.id = preps_contracted_reps_cstm.id_c
     LEFT OUTER JOIN email_addr_bean_rel ON email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id = preps_contracted_reps_cstm.id_c
     LEFT OUTER JOIN email_addresses ON email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id = email_addresses.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cstm ON wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c = wn_writing_number.id
    WHERE wn_writing_number_cstm.wn_writing_number_id_c = passId AND wn_writing_number.deleted = '0' AND preps_contracted_reps.deleted = '0' AND wn_writing_number.deleted = '0' AND email_addr_bean_rel.deleted = '0'
    GROUP BY wn_writing_number.`name`;

    INSERT INTO `pendingBusiness`(`title_c`, `name`, `rep_first_name`, `rep_last_name`, `id_c`, `contact_status_reps_c`, `investor_first_name`, `investor_last_name`, `product_detail`, `paperwork_status_c`, `next_step`, `outstanding_requirements_c`, `funding_status_c`, `funding_next_step_c`, `fulfillment_status_c`, `fulfillment_next_step_c`, `amount`, `stage`, `date_entered`, `case_manager`, `lost_sale_date_c`, `compensation_run_c`, `product_id`, `rep_state`, `investor_state`)
    SELECT
    wn_writing_number_cstm.title_c, 
    wn_writing_number.`name`,
    preps_contracted_reps.first_name, 
    preps_contracted_reps.last_name, 
    wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c, 
    preps_contracted_reps_cstm.contact_status_reps_c, 
    contacts.first_name, 
    contacts.last_name, 
    aos_products.`name`, 
    opportunities_cstm.paperwork_status_c, 
    opportunities.next_step, 
    opportunities_cstm.outstanding_requirements_c, 
    opportunities_cstm.funding_status_c, 
    opportunities_cstm.funding_next_step_c, 
    opportunities_cstm.fulfillment_status_c, 
    opportunities_cstm.fulfillment_next_step_c, 
    opportunities.amount,
    opportunities_cstm.stage_c,
    opportunities.date_entered,
    CONCAT(users.first_name, " ", users.last_name) AS case_manager,
    opportunities_cstm.lost_sale_date_c,
    opportunities_cstm.compensation_run_c,
    aos_products.id,
    preps_contracted_reps.primary_address_state,
    opportunities_cstm.state_of_residence_c
FROM wn_writing_number 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1wn_writing_number_idb = wn_writing_number.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_cont9effed_reps_ida = preps_contracted_reps.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps_cstm ON preps_contracted_reps.id = preps_contracted_reps_cstm.id_c
     LEFT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cstm ON wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c = wn_writing_number.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN opportunities_cstm ON opportunities_cstm.wn_writing_number_id_c = wn_writing_number.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts ON opportunities_cstm.contact_id_c = contacts.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN opportunities ON opportunities_cstm.id_c = opportunities.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN aos_products ON opportunities_cstm.aos_products_id_c = aos_products.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON opportunities_cstm.user_id_c = users.id
WHERE wn_writing_number.id = passId AND opportunities.deleted = '0' AND opportunities.date_entered >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1.5 YEAR)
GROUP BY opportunities_cstm.id_c;

    SET lastLayer := 0;
    SET lastInsertCount := 1;

    LayerLoop: WHILE lastInsertCount > 0 DO
      INSERT INTO `temp`(`layer`, `title_c`, `name`, `rep_first_name`, `rep_last_name`, `id_c`, `contact_status_reps_c`, `phone_mobile`,`contract_type_c`,`email_address`)
      SELECT lastLayer + 1,
        wn_writing_number_cstm.title_c, 
        wn_writing_number.`name`, 
        preps_contracted_reps.first_name, 
        preps_contracted_reps.last_name, 
        wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c,
        preps_contracted_reps_cstm.contact_status_reps_c, 
        preps_contracted_reps.phone_mobile, 
        preps_contracted_reps_cstm.contract_type_c, 
        email_addresses.email_address
    FROM wn_writing_number LEFT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing946b_number_ida = wn_writing_number.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp ON wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing3148nt_comp_idb = cac_customize_agent_comp.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm ON cac_customize_agent_comp.id = cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c = aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.aos_produca2b8nt_comp_idb
         LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1wn_writing_number_idb = wn_writing_number.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_cont9effed_reps_ida = preps_contracted_reps.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps_cstm ON preps_contracted_reps.id = preps_contracted_reps_cstm.id_c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN email_addr_bean_rel ON email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id = preps_contracted_reps_cstm.id_c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN email_addresses ON email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id = email_addresses.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cstm ON wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c = wn_writing_number.id
      WHERE wn_writing_number_cstm.wn_writing_number_id_c IN (SELECT id_c FROM `temp` WHERE layer = lastLayer) AND wn_writing_number.deleted = '0' AND preps_contracted_reps.deleted = '0' AND wn_writing_number.deleted = '0' AND email_addr_bean_rel.deleted = '0'
      GROUP BY wn_writing_number.`name`;

      SET lastInsertCount := ROW_COUNT();

      INSERT INTO `pendingBusiness`(`layer`, `title_c`, `name`, `rep_first_name`, `rep_last_name`, `id_c`, `contact_status_reps_c`, `investor_first_name`, `investor_last_name`, `product_detail`, `paperwork_status_c`, `next_step`, `outstanding_requirements_c`, `funding_status_c`, `funding_next_step_c`, `fulfillment_status_c`, `fulfillment_next_step_c`, `amount`, `stage`, `date_entered`, `case_manager`, `lost_sale_date_c`, `compensation_run_c`, `product_id`, `rep_state`, `investor_state`)
      SELECT lastLayer + 1,
        wn_writing_number_cstm.title_c, 
        wn_writing_number.`name`, 
        preps_contracted_reps.first_name, 
        preps_contracted_reps.last_name, 
        wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c, 
        preps_contracted_reps_cstm.contact_status_reps_c, 
        contacts.first_name, 
        contacts.last_name, 
        aos_products.`name`, 
        opportunities_cstm.paperwork_status_c, 
        opportunities.next_step, 
        opportunities_cstm.outstanding_requirements_c, 
        opportunities_cstm.funding_status_c, 
        opportunities_cstm.funding_next_step_c, 
        opportunities_cstm.fulfillment_status_c, 
        opportunities_cstm.fulfillment_next_step_c, 
        opportunities.amount,
        opportunities_cstm.stage_c,
        opportunities.date_entered,
        CONCAT(users.first_name, " ", users.last_name) AS case_manager,
        opportunities_cstm.lost_sale_date_c,
        opportunities_cstm.compensation_run_c,
        aos_products.id,
        preps_contracted_reps.primary_address_state,
        opportunities_cstm.state_of_residence_c
    FROM wn_writing_number 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1wn_writing_number_idb = wn_writing_number.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_cont9effed_reps_ida = preps_contracted_reps.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps_cstm ON preps_contracted_reps.id = preps_contracted_reps_cstm.id_c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cstm ON wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c = wn_writing_number.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN opportunities_cstm ON opportunities_cstm.wn_writing_number_id_c = wn_writing_number.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts ON opportunities_cstm.contact_id_c = contacts.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN opportunities ON opportunities_cstm.id_c = opportunities.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN aos_products ON opportunities_cstm.aos_products_id_c = aos_products.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON opportunities_cstm.user_id_c = users.id
      WHERE opportunities.deleted = '0' AND wn_writing_number_cstm.wn_writing_number_id_c IN (SELECT id_c FROM `temp` WHERE layer = lastLayer) AND opportunities.date_entered >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1.5 YEAR)
      GROUP BY opportunities_cstm.id_c;

      SET lastLayer := lastLayer + 1;
    END WHILE LayerLoop;


    SELECT `title_c`, `name`, `rep_first_name`, `rep_last_name`, `id_c`, `contact_status_reps_c`, `investor_first_name`, `investor_last_name`, `product_detail`, `paperwork_status_c`, `next_step`, `outstanding_requirements_c`, `funding_status_c`, `funding_next_step_c`, `fulfillment_status_c`, `fulfillment_next_step_c`, `amount`, `stage`, `date_entered`, `case_manager`, `lost_sale_date_c`, `compensation_run_c`, `product_id`, `rep_state`, `investor_state`
    FROM `pendingBusiness`
    ORDER BY rep_first_name ASC;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pendingBusiness`;
END
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using only ```LEFT OUTER JOIN```s? At least any table appearing in the where clause can be converted to ```INNER JOIN```s and that should give you a boost. If you understand what the join statements are doing, I would encourage you to convert all of the joins to inner joins.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/KXdIwmw.png) is a diagram of the `JOIN` statement done for the pendingBusiness Table. Just for kicks, I converted them all into `INNER JOINS`, however, no rows were returned. My understanding of the difference is fuzzy. I just know that doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` often returns what I need.

Comment: If you don't understand how the joins are working, try at least converting any table in where clauses to inner joins.

Comment: I did so, it worked. The performance gain, however, was only .02-.03 seconds. When I run a `show profiles;` it shows that the time being taken is primarily with the `INSERT INTO` statements, not the select statements. One bite at a time I suppose.

Comment: Try adding a primary key to your tables; also try using temporary tables instead of creating a regular table and dropping afterwards. Lastly there is no better way to improve the efficiency of a query than to completely understand what they are doing and what your needs are.

Comment: You're going to have a very rough time trying to analyze performance inside a stored procedure like this. The steps to sorting out this performance trouble are: first, do EXPLAIN for each SELECT statement, leaving aside the INSERT INTO. Second: add appropriate indexes to speed up those SELECT statements, and convince yourself they're fast enough. Third, add back the INSERT statements and get most of your logic working.  Fourth, wrap up the result in your stored procedure. If you skip the first two steps, you'll be baffled for the indefinite future.

Comment: Also, you are misusing the nasty nasty nonstandard MySQL extension to GROUP BY. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: How much RAM?  You really should move to InnoDB.

Comment: No indexes!?!  Gag me with a spoon!

Comment: Here... study my [_meager index cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, your query is functionally identical to the following. However, the following has the advantage of being easier to read. That said, your GROUP BY clause will return (potentially) indeterminate results for all but `name`.

```
SELECT 0
     , k.title_c
     , a.name
     , g.first_name
     , g.last_name
     , k.id_c
     , h.contact_status_reps_c
     , g.phone_mobile
     , h.contract_type_c
     , j.email_address
  FROM wn_writing_number a
  JOIN wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c b
    ON b.wn_writing946b_number_ida = a.id
  JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp c
    ON c.id = b.wn_writing3148nt_comp_idb 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm d 
    ON d.id_c = c.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c e 
    ON e.aos_produca2b8nt_comp_idb = d.id_c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c f
    ON f.preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1wn_writing_number_idb = a.id 
  JOIN preps_contracted_reps g
    ON g.id = f.preps_cont9effed_reps_ida
  LEFT 
  JOIN preps_contracted_reps_cstm h
    ON h.id_c = g.id  
  JOIN email_addr_bean_rel i
    ON i.bean_id = h.id_c
  LEFT 
  JOIN email_addresses j
    ON j.id = i.email_address_id  
  JOIN wn_writing_number_cstm k
    ON k.id_c = a.id
 WHERE k.wn_writing_number_id_c = passId 
   AND a.deleted = 0 
   AND g.deleted = 0 
   AND i.deleted = 0
 GROUP 
    BY a.name;
```